# Will Installing PHP on IIS 7 Interrupt Active Server Pages

Tags: php, iis-7

I am getting ready to migrate from a classic ASP build to php on the same server.  Now I'm getting ready to install PHP on the server and I'm getting cold feet.  Should I expect any interruption to my ability to host ASP files?  Are there any problems that occur from installing PHP on IIS 7?  Significant down time is not an option.  Thanks for any input from somebody who has gone through the process.

Comment: All the companies I have ever worked for have a Quality environment and a production environment.  We would test things out first in Quality **before** touching production, which might impact users.  You should also have a plan to back out the changes in case things go bad. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, set yourself up a test environment to try out any changes you would want to make.  Your test environment should mimic your production environment as closely as possible.  If the tests work, then roll the changes out to your production environment.